# Cobertura grails code coverage

Tags: grails, gradle, groovy, code-coverage, cobertura

I'm adding cobertura code coverage for my grails 3.1.6 project, the coverage report seems to be bit off, i.e I have unit test cases ( both pos & neg case) to cover a if block, but the report says no coverage for that if -block.
Gradle: 2.13
Groovy: 2.4.5
grails: 3.1.6
cobertura gradle plugin: net.saliman:gradle-cobertura-plugin:2.3.2

Here is my code

```
if (params == null || params.isEmpty()) {
       return []
}
```

My unit test pass empty params and null for params

coverage report say

> 'Conditional coverage: 0% 0/6 [each condition: 0%, 0%, 0% ]'

any idea what I'm doing wrong ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

It might be late. But the reason being that the "**If**" is an conditional check. So in other to increase this. The Params should be tested with **Null** and Also **empty** so that implies both conditions will have to be resolved and once it should skip the entire **if block** so that becomes 3 conditions.